# j center or something else?

Tags: react-native, jcenter

please somebody help me on this
i made a react native project with the command line react-native init and when i wanna open test it while my android emulator is open and i run it with the command line react-native run android i get this messege

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/5.153.35.248] failed: Connection timed out: connect

i try everthing to fix it but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

open folder `android` in your project folder

in which you can find `build.gradle` open this file

at the and of the file you can find

```
 allprojects {
    repositories{
        ...
      }  
 }
```

add `google()` in to it like this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i did that and again this  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'H:\React\code\relaxationstation\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'relaxationstation'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

Comment: ok then check the class path of your android studio and set that version same as in react native project build gradle file